# import scoped package from local in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Currently we have multiple node package published in this format

- @company/module1
- @company/module2

I would like to be able to load these module from local without installing it so we can modify the code directly.

So I make the link in the folder tree like this

```
- company/
-- module1 -> ../../module1  
-- module2 -> ../../module2
```

Now I want when I import from the scoped name, it will load from local files instead

```js
import module1 from '@company/module1'
```

Load from my other folder instead of looking from node_modules instalations.

Can anyone help me on this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you using typescript or javascript?

Comment: It's Typescript

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** import the modules, libraries, or a single file in the `node.js` with the common import statement `import Example from "package"`.

So, try to use the `const Example = require('package')` instead.

```
const module1 = require("path/to/the/module1");
const module2 = require("path/to/the/module2");
```